# What is the Github HTTP rate limit (Not API limit)?

Tags: http, github, github-api

What is the Github HTTP request limit?

I made a crawler to crawl data from Github, but sometimes it returns with error code 429 which is "Too many request", so I would like to know what is the Github request limit per minute or per hour?

Answer (score 0):

The rate limits are based on the token (pat, oauth, app, deploy key) that you are using and the value varies based on the kind of license (free, pro, team, Enterprise) your account falls under and she kind of API you are accessing (public API, private API, Rest or GraphQL)

The docs for rate limits can be found here:

- https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/resources-in-the-rest-api#rate-limiting
- https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/rate-limit